# Memory issues with ARC on iOS and Mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, memory-management, screen

I am trying to mirror screen of my mac to iphone. I have this method in Mac app delegate to capture screeen into base64 string.

```
-(NSString*)baseString{
CGImageRef screen = CGDisplayCreateImage(displays[0]);

CGFloat w = CGImageGetWidth(screen);
CGFloat h = CGImageGetHeight(screen);

NSImage * image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:screen size:(NSSize){w,h}];
[image lockFocus];
NSBitmapImageRep *bitmapRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithFocusedViewRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, w, h)];
[bitmapRep setCompression:NSTIFFCompressionJPEG factor:.3];
[image unlockFocus];

NSData *imageData = [bitmapRep representationUsingType:NSJPEGFileType properties:_options];
NSString *base64String = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
image = nil;
bitmapRep = nil;
imageData = nil;

return base64String;}
```

after that I am sending it to iphone and present it in UIImageView.
Delay between screenshots is 40 miliseconds. Everything works as expected until there is enough memory. After minute of streaming it starts swapping and use 6GB of RAM. iOS app memory usage is also growing lineary. By the time iOS reaches 90MB of ram, mac has 6GB.
Even if I stop streaming memory is not released.
I'm using ARC in both projects. Would it make any difference if migrate it to manual reference counting ? 

I also tried     @autoreleasepool {...} block, but it didn't help.
**Any ideas ?**

**EDIT**

My iOS code is here

```
NSString message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data:image/png;base64,%@",base64];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:message];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

UIImage *ret = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
self.image.image = ret;
```

Comment: Did you read the docs for `CGDisplayCreateImage`?

Comment: I used Apple Sample code of capturing the screen, I though that NSData was causing leaks

Comment: The `NSData` will be autoreleased.

Comment: You haven't posted enough information about your iOS code. The iOS code you posted looks fine (no memory leaks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a serious memory leak. The docs for `CGDisplayCreateImage` clearly state:

> The caller is responsible for releasing the image created by calling CGImageRelease.

Update your code with a call to:

```
CGImageRelease(screen);
```

I'd add that just after creating the `NSImage`.

Comment: Sigh... You posted your answer while I was editing mine... :)

Answer (score 1):

We can't help with your iOS memory leaks since you didn't post your iOS code, but I see a big memory leak in your Mac code.

You are calling a Core Foundation function, `CGDisplayCreateImage`. Core Foundation objects are not managed by ARC. If a Core Foundation function has "Create" (or "copy") in the name then it follows the "[**create rule**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029)" and you are responsible for releasing the returned CF object when you are done with it.

Some CF objects have special release calls. For those that don't, just call `CFRelease`. `CGImageRef` has a special release call, `CGImageRelease()`.

You need a corresponding call to `CGImageRelease(screen)`, probably after the call to `initWithCGImage`.

Comment: Thanks, I used ScreenCapture Apple example code and they didn't release it after capturing. Thanks for help !! this is my iOS code
`message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data:image/png;base64,%@",message];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:message];
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        
        UIImage *ret = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        self.image.image = ret;`